# Graphing more complicated trigonometric functions in R

Tags: r, trigonometry

This should hopefully not be a very hard question—I'm just not very experienced in R.

If I want to graph a simple sine wave, all I have to is:

```
x=seq(-20,20,0.001)
y=seq(-20,20,0.001)
y=sin(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

But let's say I want to graph a relationship with trigonometric functions on both sides, such as sin(x) = cos(y). Typing:

```
sin(x) = cos(y)
```

Gives me the following error

```
Error in sin(x) = cos(y) : could not find function "sin<-"
```

Now, the obvious solution is to just rearrange it in terms of one variable, such as x = asin(cos(y)). But with much more complicated equations with multiple nested trigonometric functions on both sides, this no longer becomes viable.

I'm sure I'm missing something extremely obvious, but what is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the relationship sin on the x axis and cos on the y axis:

```
plot(sin(x),  cos(y), type = "l")
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: That's not quite what I want to do. I want to plot x and y, given the defined relationship of sin(x) = cos(y).

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your equal sign. The expression `sin(x) = cos(y)` is an assignment. If you would like to check where they are equal, then you should write `sin(x) == cos(x)`.